# transfer message between different user controls in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a video player window using WPF/C#, which contains some parts, a monitor, a slider and some player buttons, just like the following image shows:

[image]
Since if all the user control objects are written in a single .xaml, the file will be large and difficult to edit. So I split the control objects into several different .xaml files, for example, I defined a `public partial class player_control : UserControl` which contains all the player buttons. But now I don't know how to pass messages from this UserControl to other controls, e.g. the slider `player_slider`. Normally, if we clicked the button of next frame, the function `player_slider.ValueChange` will be triggered, but I don't know how to implement such kind of functions.

I am a newcomer to WPF/C#, please help me with the question.

Comment: Go download Prism and use the EventAggregator...http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is define messages in the Player control, one for each button:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent PlayEvent = EventManager.RegisterEvent( "Play", . . . );

public event RoutedEventHandler Play {
    add { AddHandler( PlayEvent, value ); }
    remove { RemoveHandler( PlayEvent, value ); }
}

public static readonly RoutedEvent StopEvent = EventManager.RegisterEvent( "Stop", . . . );

public event RoutedEventHandler Stop {
    add { AddHandler( StopEvent, value ); }
    remove { Removehandler( StopEvent, value ); }
}

. . .
```

Then any other controls that need to do something when the user clicks on the one of the buttons just need to subscribe to the event:

```
<local:PlayerButtons Play="PlayerButtons_Play" Stop="PlayerButtons_Stop" />
```

After that, you can put whatever code you need into the `PlayerButtons_Play` & `PlayerButtons_Stop` methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement this. For example, we could expose public properties & methods in each control. Then access those methods from the instance variable to send messages. Also we can keep the reference of these custom controls in a Application level class to easy access.

Alternatively, we could also implement publisher/subscriber model. Where each control can subscribe to specific events for notifications and also raise events based on their functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From the kind of Application you are having I will guess that you need to handle events across  different user controls rather than sharing properties. Because from what you have in you screenshot you will want to handle Play/Pause, Stop, Next, Back etc... events across.

For that kind of scenario my best bet would be mediator pattern, you can search on that for better understanding. In short there will be a mediator sitting in between which will be used by your two controls to communicate with each other.

Reference for Mediator Pattern.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/The-Mediator-Pattern-c2c07b54

Answer (score 0):

The same way other controls give you access to properties - via Dependency Properties. You can bind to a Sliders value via its Value property like `<Slider Value={Binding MySliderValueProperty} .. />`

To do the same you can create your own `DependencyProperty` in your `player_control` which you can then bind to.

```
public static DependencyProperty SliderValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SliderValue", typeof(double), typeof(player_control), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(double), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

and then bind it in your view

```
<controls:player_control SliderValue={Binding MySliderValueProperty} ../>
```

the "Value Changed" would then be in the setter of your bound property, just like a regular Slider

```
public string MySliderValueProperty
{
    get { return m_SliderValue; }
    set
    {
        if (m_SliderValue == value)
            return;

        // here we have an updated value
        m_SliderValue = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MySliderValueProperty);
    }
}
```

It's then a matter of connecting it with the control that is the *actual* slider so that that value is connected to the `SliderValue`.